# Is there a way to check the applied CPS value in Jmeter?

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, response-time, cps

I am trying t control the bandwidth in Jmeter using CPS value at runtime by using following command : *jmeter -Jhttpclient.socket.http.cps=12800 -Jhttpclient.socket.https.cps=12800 -n -t [JMX path] -l [Results path]*

**Is there a way to check the applied CPS value in Jmeter? Is there any command to print the applied CPS value in jmeter logs?**

Answer (score 0):

1. Also when the properties are set and the `cps` is above zero you should see the following messages in [jmeter.log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging):

   ```
   INFO o.a.j.JMeter: Setting JMeter property: httpclient.socket.http.cps=12800
   INFO o.a.j.JMeter: Setting JMeter property: httpclient.socket.https.cps=12800
   ```
2. If you want to just print the property value you can use any suitable [JSR223 Test Element](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223) and the following piece of [Groovy code](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy):

   ```
   log.info('HTTP CPS: ' + props.get('httpclient.socket.http.cps'))
   log.info('HTTPS CPS: ' + props.get('httpclient.socket.https.cps'))
   ```

   [image]
3. In case you want to see whether the real throughput exceeds the one you set via properties you can check a listener like [Aggregate Report](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Aggregate_Report), it shows the throughput in KB/s

   [image]